# Returning the property of another model that is bound to a Model in the first model

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I'm trying to access the Question list from within the TestModel and return the QuestionModel's Property.

I need to return it in the TestModel to determine the questions to be contained in a test, but I can't, I can't find where I went wrong.

```
public class TestModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<QuestionModel> Question { get; set; }=new List<QuestionModel>();             
    }


 public class QuestionModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public AppUser User { get; set; }
        public string Question { get; set; }
        public bool check { get; set; } 
        public List<TestModel>? Tests { get; set; } = new List<TestModel>();    
    }
```

I used TestModel as one of the tuple objects.

Since the code is long, I only shared the area where I had problems.

```
  @model Tuple<IList<TestModel>,IList<UserViewModel>>
    <table class="table table-striped">
@{
    int i = 0;
}
     @foreach (var item in Model.Item1)
        {
<form id="form[@i]" class="container m-xl-2">
            
            <tr id="Allquest_@i" hidden="hidden">
                <td colspan="5">
                    <div>
    
                        <input asp-for=@Model.Item1[i].Id hidden>
                            @for (int indexQuest = 0; indexQuest < item.Question.Count; indexQuest++)
                            {
                            <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.Item1[i].Question[indexQuest].check" checked="@Model.Item1[i].Question[indexQuest].check">
                            <a>@Model.Item1[i].Question[indexQuest].Question</a>
                            <br />
                            }
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="submit" asp-controller="Test" asp-action="DeleteQuestionToTest" formmethod="post" class="btn btn-danger">Seçili Soruları Sil</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
</form>
            i++;
            }
```

Here I tried to capture it as a TestModel. I tried to capture it as a list and as a single model, but I couldn't.

```
  [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult DeleteQuestionToTest([Bind(Prefix ="Item1")] IList<TestModel> tests)
        {           
            return View();
        }
```

How can I fix the code?

[image: page source]

[image: My View]

[image: ControllerFirstTry]

[image: ControllerSecondTry]

Comment: Hi @Berk KAEASU, did you use `i++` in your view? By using your current code and set the `i` and `i++`, I can receive the TestModel's Id with QuestionModel's check property successfully.

Comment: I'm using i++, I forgot to add it here while trying to shorten the code, thank you for letting me know.

Comment: Hi @Berk KAEASU, did you want to receive  TestModel instead of IList<TestModel>? By using your code, I can receive the TestModel's Id with QuestionModel's check property successfully.

Comment: I tried both IList<TestModel> and TestModel, but no results. Whichever returned a value, I would complete the code accordingly.

Comment: Hi @Berk KARASU, maybe you need share your whole view, actually It works fine by using you current code.

Comment: I added the screenshots, I wrote the view part in Turkish, I hope it doesn't cause problems in understanding.

Comment: Hi @Berk KARASU, view screenshot is not helpful for trouble shooting, pls F12 in the browser and check the input name if they match the property.

Comment: Hi @Rena , I also added the page source, sorry I could get back to you after a long time.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a workaround by creating a separate form and specifying it in the html of the models.

```
@model Tuple<IList<TestModel>,IList<UserViewModel>>
    <table class="table table-striped">
@{
    int i = 0;
}
    <form id="MainForm" asp-controller="Test" asp-action="DeleteQuestionToTest" formmethod="post"></form>
     @foreach (var item in Model.Item1)
        {
<form id="form[@i]" class="container m-xl-2">
            
            <tr id="Allquest_@i" hidden="hidden">
                <input asp-for=@Model.Item1[i].Id form="MainForm" hidden>
            <td colspan="5">
                <div>
                        @for (int indexQuest = 0; indexQuest < item.Question.Count; indexQuest++)
                        {

                        <input asp-for="@Model.Item1[i].Question[indexQuest].Id" form="MainForm" hidden>
                        <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.Item1[i].Question[indexQuest].check" form="MainForm" checked="@Model.Item1[i].Question[indexQuest].check">
                        <a>@Model.Item1[i].Question[indexQuest].Question</a>
                        <br />
                        }
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="submit" form="MainForm" class="btn btn-danger">Seçili Soruları Sil</button>
            </td>
            </tr>
</form>
            i++;
            }
```

> I returned all the tests this was a workaround, I have no idea how to return a single test.

[image]